# Retrieving data from Parse using Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parse-platform

I need a bit help, I've made a pickerview and i want to retrieve it's data from Parse.

I need to assign values to array and show it on Picker View.

Help me guys.
Thanks.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()


        let pickerView = UIPickerView()
        pickerView.delegate = self
        doctor.inputView = pickerView

        let query = PFQuery(className: "doctors")
        //wherekey can be omited
        query.whereKey("doctorId", equalTo:"1")

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in

            if let objects = objects {

                for object in objects {

                    self.doctorNames.append(object["doctorNames"] as! String)

                    pickerView.reloadAllComponents()

                }

            }


        })
}
```

And Here my pickerView Functions:

```
  func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return doctorNames.count
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return doctorNames[row]
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        doctor.text = doctorNames[row]  //bad inscturctions error on this line
    }
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with doctor, So not sure about that part. Have to tried to print the objects returned from parse? what is the actual issue that your having? are the values not being returned? or they are returned but not showing in the picker view?

Comment: doctors is parse table name, doctor is the name of textfield that takes the value of viewPicker. My main problem is values not being returned. I need to take these values.

Comment: What does your log display ?

Comment: My log says:  fatal error: Array index out of range

Comment: You need to provide some additional info to get help with this issue, can you provide the values passed to objects and error? is there any suggestion of what array is out of bounds? how is the array defined?

Comment: array defined like that:  var doctorNames = [String]() , doctor.text = doctorNames[row]  this line gives error because array is empty.

Comment: Ok, so we need to debug your PFQuery, whether it actually returns anything at all? can you print out objects and error in the closure? should "1" be 1?

Comment: self.doctorNames.append(object["doctorNames"] as! String) when we write this, it returns nothing but when we write another test statement instead of this it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE: I cannot post well formatted code in the comments, so I'll put this here for now. If I manage to solve the issue then I'll leave it here with edits, if not I'll delete it shortly.

It's possible that the query is not returning anything or doctorNames is not a valid property on the returned object. try this code and let us know the result

```
if let objects = objects {
    print("objects returned: \(objects)")
    for object in objects {
        print("adding object to pickerView: \(object)")
        self.doctorNames.append(object["doctorNames"] as! String)
    }
    // also I'd put this outside of the loop
    pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
} else {
    print("something went wrong here. Objects is: \(objects), error is: \(error)")
}
```

EDIT:

After the op posting log results, the error was in the filter. adding `query.whereKey("doctorId", equalTo:"1")` did not return any results. Omitting this line will return all results though.

Comment: How do I sort these values alphabetically before printing to screen? Is there any way?

Comment: you should be able to add a sort property on the query in parse, otherwise you'd need to use the global sort function provided by swift.

Comment: query.orderByAscending("doctorNames") is the solution :} Thanks a lot again.